# How to click button from form 1 and button from another form already clicking

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I want to click button from form 2 and button from form 1 at the same time.

If anyone can please suggest any ideas for this, it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

This my code

**Form 2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form    
  {
    Form1 ths;
    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ths = frm;

        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ths.button1_2= button1;

    }
}
```

**Form 1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Form2(this).Show();
    }
    private void button1_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Dot Net Perls is awesome.");

    }
}
```

I think problem at this line `ths.button1_2= button1;` because I modify from 
`ths.textBox1.Text = textBox1_2.Text;` but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: You want to click on `Form2.Button1`. When you do that, you want `Form1.Button1` to be clicked, too? (i. e. you want to call `Form1.Button1`'s `OnClick`)

Comment: `I want to click button from form 2 and button from form 1 already clicking in the same time.` I have no idea what you are trying to say here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ths.button1_2.PerformClick();
}
```

**NOTE**: It may solve your problem but in fact we don't do such a thing, we can always define some event, delegate or method to call directly rather via the programmatic clicking.